# Why is my user shown twice when I commit via Terminal to Github?

Tags: github, terminal

I recently came across this problem: I committed (via Terminal) some code to a repo on Github. Looking at this repo on Github, it shows my user twice for the same commit.

[Screenshot of repo with a commit with same user twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCahx.png)

Also in a totally clean repo I created, it does the same (https://github.com/bennisan86/testingtwo). I can't seem to find specific help on this topic in the github-help section, so I don't really know where to begin (I'm kind of a newbee so please be gently). I tried running 'git config --list', hoping that I would see in this list which user is used for commit, but this didn't make me any wiser, since I didn't see the word 'user' anywhere in the presented output of that command.

Comment: Please, make the question title more descriptive, if it's GitHub related problem, GitHub should be int he title. And, please, provide a sample text example or an sample image to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The link no longer works.

Comment: Changed the title, removed the link (it was to a private repo, I apologize).